# Exporting more than one image in one JPG file

Tags: java, jsp, arrays, jfreechart

I have a JSP that allows the user to export some data. You can choose differents formats (excel, csv). Also, with the excel are exported the charts corresponding to the data (pie chart, line chart and bar chart) The user want to export the charts in a unique jpg file.

What I did is (all in Java):

- Generate the charts using JFreeChart
- Convert the chart into a JPG image using: ChartUtilities.saveChartAsJPEG
- Then I retrieve theimage bytes:

The code:

```
InputStream is = null;
try {
   is = new FileInputStream(image);
}catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
byte[] bytes = null;
try {
   bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
}catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is working well, I have the bytes for each chart. Then I put the bytes for each chart in a byte array:

```
byte[] imageBytes = getImageAsBytes(chart1,chart2,chart3);
res.setContentType("image/jpg");
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "MyCharts" + ".jpg");
res.setContentLength(imageBytes.length);
try{
    OutputStream output = res.getOutputStream();
    output.write(imageBytes);
    output.flush();   
    output.close();  
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**The problem is**: when I open the JPG, **only one image is displayed**. I tested the export for each chart and works well, but when I put all the chart bytes, is only displayed one image (always the first in the imageBytes array)

I don't know if I have to create some kind of canvas, or just is not possible put 3 images or more in the same JPG by this way.

Comment: If you're talking about putting multiple images into separate compartments inside one file, then JPEG doesn't support this. You will need to use TIFF.

Answer (score 1):

The JPG file format isn't going to let you get away with that.  My suggestion would be to create a new `BufferedImage` with a large enough canvas to contain all three images, render your three images onto it at staggered Y axis offsets, and then dump it out to JPG with `ImageIO`.

Comment: But then how I can attach this ImageIO? Because on this way I have to use something like: ImageIO.write(myImage, "jpg", new File(
"some path"));  but I don't want to save the image in any path, i want to download the image on the browser

Comment: You can use the write method that takes an `OutputStream` and pass it the stream from your servlet response: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write(java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream)